# Setting up Spring Data Neo4j examples

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and Java and am trying to get the Spring Data Neo4J examples (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/) to work.

Apparently the reason why most of the examples don't work anymore is because there were some major changes with the latest version of Spring Data Neo4j (SDN 3.0).

There was another post ([Errors of the Cineasts examples of Spring data neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356398/errors-of-the-cineasts-examples-of-spring-data-neo4j)) that mentioned adding the "base-package" attribute in both the neo4j:config and neo4j:repositories elements. I tried doing that and got an additional error: "The prefix "neo4j" for element "neo4j:config" is not bound."

Comment: I up voted this question. I think the biggest thing the spring folks could do to increase adoption of sdn4j would be to provide examples that work out of the box and updated documentation, for example an updated version of the good relationships book. I have noticed that while the version number at the top of the book has been updated over releases, the content of the book has not, which makes the actual contents out of date, incompatible with the documented target version number and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research and much trial and error, I was able to get the cineasts sample project to work. Hopefully this will save you a lot of time.

For the two "Error: cvc-complex-type.4:Attribute 'bases-package' must appear on element 'neo4j:config'" errors, add the base-package attributes (base-package="org.neo4j.cineasts.domain") to the neo4j:config tags in applicationContext.xml (in the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder) and movies-test-context.xml (in the test/resources folder).

The other error from tx.close() being undefined can be fixed by changing it to tx.finish().

To run the project, run the Maven build with jetty:run as the goal. Make sure you are using a jdk and not just a jre. I ran it with a jre and got an error and had to run the Maven build with jetty:stop to kill the server before I could re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks! I followed those steps and was able to deploy the example! Now I have to figure out how to load the nodes into the example.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the same boat, also just started with Neo4j and SDN. The error you're getting would be due to not having xmlns:neo4j declared, but you might have some other issues so including the whole file below. My repositories, annotated beans etc. are all in subpackages of com.purr.justtravel.neo4j.

I am not using Spring data examples per se, rather doing my own stuff based on these examples, but the following config starts fine for me.

You can switch between in-memory database and in-process (but with disk storage) version. The in memory database is simply created with new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase(), which I wrapped in a static factory method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" />

    <!-- SAME PROCESS DATABASE -->
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="neo4jdb/store/graph.db" base-package="com.purr.justtravel.neo4j"/>
     <!-- IN MEMORY DATABASE -->
<!--     <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.purr.justtravel.neo4j" /> -->
<!--     <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="com.purr.justtravel.server.AbstractInMemoryNeo4jTest" factory-method="createNeo4jDatabase" /> -->

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.purr.justtravel.neo4j" />

</beans>
```